# How get values inside min(), max() in zod?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I have the following schema.

```
const schema = z.object({
 name: z.string().min(1)
})
```

Is there any way in zod to get the value stored in min?

```
const minValue = schema.shape...? // should be 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, after a little poking around, there's a hidden `_def` field that you probably need to `//@ts-ignore`:

```
const minValue = schema.shape.name._def.checks[0].value;
```

If you have more than one check, you can find the one you want:

```
const minValue = schema.shape.name._def.checks.find(({ kind }) => kind === "min").value;
```

Note that `find` will return `undefined` if no such check was found.

---

But may I interest you in an alternative?

```js
const nameMinLength = 1;

const schema = z.object({
 name: z.string().min(nameMinLength)
});

// now you already have it
console.log(nameMinLength);
```